# How to add an extension method?

Tags: c#

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract()]
public sealed class B: BaseB
{
    public B()
    {
        SourceContainerFolderName = string.Empty;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "sourceContainer ")]
    public string SourceContainer { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "sourceContainerFolderName ")]
    public string SourceContainerFolderName { get; set; }

    public A GetA()
    {
        return new A
        {
            ContainerName = SourceContainer,
            FolderName = SourceContainerFolderName,
        };
    }
}
```

Please, help me to create an extension method instedof method in DataContract - `GetA()`. I want to remove this method from my class and use extension method. How to do this?

Comment: Where are `A.ContainerName` and `A.FolderName` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake. Question is updated

Comment: Here's a blog post I wrote just a week ago on this exact subject. How convenient! [http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/06/25/extension-methods.html](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/06/25/extension-methods.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure i have completly understood your question, but try this :

```
public static A GetA(this B baseB)
{
    return new A
    {
        ContainerName = baseB.SourceContainer,
        FolderName = baseB.SourceContainerFolderName,
    };
}
```

Edited, this extension method will create an object of type A using an object of type B, you can use it like this :

```
B b = new B();
A a = B.GetA(); // Here's is the use of the extension
```

Comment: Whereas the syntax is correct, you should also mention, that an extension method must be defined in a `static class`.

Comment: True, my mistake ^^

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods must be defined as `static` methods in a `static class` having a special `this T` parameter as first parameter

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static A GetA(this B me) 
    {
        if (me == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return new A { 
            ContainerName = me.SourceContainer, 
            FolderName = me.SourceContainerFolderName
        };
    }

}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx for details.